# How to display a text when we hover a button who is bigger than the button?

Tags: html, css, button, text

I want to display a text when I have the cursor on a specific button to help the user.

After taking a look I have find that I could do that:

```
.stopAll {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: url('/stopAll.gif');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.stopAll:hover:before {
  content: 'Stop all running containers';
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

I want to display the text on a line, could you help me ?

[EDIT] maybe I should show the HTML too so it's like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a id="allCtn">All containers</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="rngCtn">Only running containers</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="psdCtn">Only paused containers</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="stpCtn">Only stopped containers</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="extCtn">Only exited containers</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="crtCtn">Only created containers</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><button type="button" class="stopAll {{#unless urgence}}hidden{{/unless}}"> </button>
  </li>
  <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` and `white-space: nowrap;` on pseudo element

```css
.stopAll {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: url('/stopAll.gif');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.stopAll:hover:before {
  content: 'Stop all running containers';
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top:100%;
}
```

```html
<button class=stopAll>A</button>
```

Comment: In my case it just stack the text after the button but with the same aspect as my first picture. The solution of LIJIN worked

Comment: But it's a same answer as mine.

Comment: yes now you edited it, so I'll accept yours because of quality

Answer (score 1):

You may use,

```
.stopAll {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
background: url('/stopAll.gif');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
display:block;
position:relative;  
}
.stopAll:hover:before {
 content: 'Stop all running containers';
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 white-space: nowrap;
 top:100%;
}
```

Comment: ok. you can change the placement by changing the position left or right.